# I am trying to debug my LINUX LAMP Server index.html to render a HTML image map of the United States of America, http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to debug my LINUX LAMP Server index.html to render a HTML image map of the United States of America, http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/.

I am encountering the following problem. First, I can render simple HTML text using simple Javascript functions. However, when I try to render a HTML image map of the United States of America, http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/., my web browser shows nothing except an text control labeled jVectorMap demo.

My index.html is shown below. Please let me know what mistakes I have made coding index.html. Thank you very much for reading this question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="us_aea_en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    function processOrder() { ('USA-map').vectorMap({map: 'us_aea_en'}); }
  </script>
</body>
<body>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
processOrder();
</Script>
</body>)
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is not valid (you should never have multiple `<body>` elements: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/html.html#html), and you really should be using a "on DOM ready" wrapper, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js"></script>
      <script>
            $(function(){   
                $('#USA-map').vectorMap({map: 'us_aea_en'});
            });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tiesomn T., Thank you for your correct answer. I just tested it and it works. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer. Here I my revised index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.css"
type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="us_aea_en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function processOrder() {
          var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
          pluginContainer.vectorMap({map: 'us_aea_en'});
    }
  </script>
</body>
<body>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
processOrder();
</Script>
```